# iOS : AWS MobileHub developer authenticated identitiy cant invoke lambda - AccessDeniedException

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub

I am using **AWS MobileHub SDK with a developer authenticated identity** setup.

The mobile hub SDK has an **AWSIdentityManager** that handles the session and
I have followed the guide [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html) to login with my identity provider.

The identity provider works fine and the login succeeds but whenever I try to make a cloudlogic call (invoke a lambda function) to fails with:

*AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSCloudLogic.m line:47 | __67-[AWSCloudLogic invokeFunction:withParameters:withCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke | invokeFunction: Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. AccessDeniedException*

This indicates that when the lambda functions are being invoked that MobileHub is not using the correct AIM role and 
Lambda is denying access. My AIM setup is fine and checked so I am not sure where the problem is.

**In the AWSIdentityManager I have modified only this function**:

```
- (AWSTask *)initializeClients:(NSDictionary *)logins {

NSLog(@"initializing clients...");

[AWSLogger defaultLogger].logLevel = AWSLogLevelError; //AWSLogLevelVerbose;
[AWSServiceConfiguration addGlobalUserAgentProductToken:AWS_MOBILEHUB_USER_AGENT];

NSString *email = [JNKeychain loadValueForKey:@"email"]; 
NSDictionary *logins = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:email forKey:developerProvider];

    id<AWSCognitoIdentityProvider> identityProvider = [[CBDeveloperAuthenticatedIdentityProvider alloc]
                                                       initWithRegionType:AMAZON_COGNITO_REGION
                                                       identityId:nil
                                                       identityPoolId:AMAZON_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID
                                                       logins:logins
                                                       providerName:developerProvider];


    self.credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]
                                initWithRegionType:AMAZON_COGNITO_REGION
                                identityProvider:identityProvider
                                unauthRoleArn:nil
                                authRoleArn:nil];

   //I have AWS_COGNITO_UNAUTH_ROLE and AWS_COGNITO_AUTH_ROLE but the docs don't seem to use them... and when I do there is no change
   //http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html





AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AMAZON_COGNITO_REGION
                                                                     credentialsProvider:self.credentialsProvider];

[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;


return [self.credentialsProvider getIdentityId];
}
```

Amazon has a lot of information scattered everywhere but I couldn't find anything out there for mobile hub with regards to developer 
authenticated identities but

Comment: If you post this in the AWS forums, we can review your IAM configuration to confirm. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=173&start=0